ATmega4809 on Arduino nano every to recieve IR signals and power the brightess of an led through PWM signals
I'm currently working on a university assignment that involves creating a system to recognize and display the hexadecimal code from an IR remote control. Additionally, the system should adjust the brightness of an LED using PWM based on the "+" and "-" buttons on the remote.
I am not allowed to use libraries except Liquidcrystal for the lcd screen.
I am encountering build errors when trying to compile this code using PlatformIO. The specific error message I am seeing is:
Indexing .pio\build\nano_every\libFrameworkArduino.a
Linking .pio\build\nano_every\firmware.elf
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWdZZlI.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0xb2): undefined reference to `setup'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0xba): undefined reference to `loop'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\nano_every\firmware.elf] Error 1

The build output does not help me at all, so i cannot understand what's not allowing the program to build.
Since I'm using the PlatformIO extension in VSCode, to add info here is my platformio.ini conf file:
; PlatformIO Project Configuration File
;
;   Build options: build flags, source filter
;   Upload options: custom upload port, speed and extra flags
;   Library options: dependencies, extra library storages
;   Advanced options: extra scripting
;
; Please visit documentation for the other options and examples
; https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf.html

[env:nano_every]
platform = atmelmegaavr
board = ATmega4809
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 9600
lib_deps = 
    arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal@^1.0.7

This is my code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

// Definition of IR codes for the "+" and "-" buttons
const unsigned long IR_BUTTON_PLUS = 0x40501505;
const unsigned long IR_BUTTON_MINUS = 0x44111144;

// Variables for managing time and IR code
volatile unsigned long irCode = 0;
volatile bool irReceived = false;
volatile int ledBrightness = 128; // Initial LED brightness
volatile unsigned long elapsedTime = 0; // Elapsed time in microseconds

// LCD display configuration (pin RS, E, D4, D5, D6, D7)
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17);

// ISR for the timer that keeps track of elapsed time in microseconds
ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect) {
  elapsedTime++;
  TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm; // Clear the interrupt flag
}

// ISR for receiving the IR signal
ISR(PORTA_PORT_vect) {
  if (PORTA.INTFLAGS & PIN2_bm) {
    static unsigned long lastTime = 0;
    static unsigned long code = 0;
    static int bitCount = 0;

    // Use the timer to get the current time
    unsigned long time = elapsedTime; // Use elapsedTime to get the time in microseconds
    unsigned long duration = time - lastTime;
    lastTime = time;

    // IR signal decoding (simplified example)
    if (duration > 1000) { // Start of a new code
      code = 0;
      bitCount = 0;
    } else {
      code = (code << 1) | (duration > 500 ? 1 : 0);
      bitCount++;
      if (bitCount == 32) {
        irCode = code;
        irReceived = true;
      }
    }
    PORTA.INTFLAGS = PIN2_bm; // Clear the interrupt flag
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize the LCD display
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("IR Code:");

  // Configure the pin for the IR signal
  PORTA.DIRCLR = PIN2_bm; // Set PA2 as input
  PORTA.PIN2CTRL = PORT_ISC_BOTHEDGES_gc; // Enable interrupt on both edges

  // Configure the timer for PWM
  TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = TCA_SINGLE_CLKSEL_DIV64_gc | TCA_SINGLE_ENABLE_bm;
  TCA0.SINGLE.PER = 255; // PWM period
  TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = TCA_SINGLE_WGMODE_SINGLESLOPE_gc | TCA_SINGLE_CMP0EN_bm;
  TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0 = ledBrightness; // Set initial brightness

  // Configure the pin for the LED PWM
  PORTD.DIRSET = PIN6_bm; // Set PD6 as output

  // Enable interrupts
  sei();
}

void loop() {
  if (irReceived) {
    irReceived = false;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(irCode, HEX);

    if (irCode == IR_BUTTON_PLUS && ledBrightness < 255) {
      ledBrightness += 16;
    } else if (irCode == IR_BUTTON_MINUS && ledBrightness > 0) {
      ledBrightness -= 16;
    }
    TCA0.SINGLE.CMP0 = ledBrightness; // Update LED brightness
  }
}

This is a representation of my IRL project quickly made on Tinkercad to give you an idea of how it's made
I’ve verified that my code adheres to the ATmega4809’s datasheet and that I’m using the correct registers and ports, but honestly at this point i may be wrong.
I've been stuck on this problem since switching from using from using arduino.h to control the I/O, so i assume it's my I/O handling that is the problem.
Thank you.

what do you mean with "since switching from using arduino.h" ???

My fault, i was unclear. This project was tested with the use of arduino.h's functions to  test the circuit. It all worked flawlessly. But now that i switched to use registers nothing works anymore.

You never declared void loop() and void setup(). How is the compiler supposed to know those functions?
Add #include <Arduino.h> to the top of your file.

That made the PlatformIO build, thank you. I noticed that without declaring arduino.h arduino ide was able to build it since the library is already built in. But it still does not work, i think the problem relies in the declaration of the ports I/O, but i honestly dont know
